# Lie bracket of two vectors $X,Y$ perpendicular to $Z$ is perpendicular to $Z$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative

Where $Z$ is a Killing vector field (is this even necessary?)
In case more assumptions are necessary, I have:
$[Z,X] = [Z,Y] = g(Z,X) = g(Z,Y) = 0$
I want to prove $g([X,Y],Z) = 0$

I am trying to prove this without using coordinates. I kind of have a rough argument using the definition of the Lie derivative (I'm moving a vector that's always perpendicular to $Z$ through a curve in the orthogonal space to $Z$ so necessarily the difference must be in the orthogonal space) but I am not sure how to formalize it and whether I can simply put the definition inside the dot product. Are the assumptions that $Z$ is a Killing vector field necessary, and what about $[Z,X] = [Z,Y] = 0$?

edit: I forgot to mention, the metric is of the form $ds^2 = \Theta dz^2 + \hat{g}_{ab}dx^adx^b$ where nothing depends on $z$. I think that the precise name for this is polarized axial symmetry, or equivalently Ernst potential is $0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be false in general. Define the following vector fields on $\mathbb R^3$:
$$
X = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - y\frac{\partial}{\partial z},
\qquad 
Y = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + x\frac{\partial}{\partial z},
\qquad 
Z = \frac{\partial}{\partial z},
$$
and let $g$ be the metric for which $\{X,Y,Z\}$ is an orthonormal basis. 
Then $Z$ is a Killing field for $g$, and $[Z,X] = [Z,Y] = g(Z,X) = g(Z,Y) = 0$; but $[X,Y]=2Z$, which is not orthogonal to $Z$.

The only issue here is whether the distribution consisting of vectors orthogonal to $Z$ is [involutive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(differential_geometry)#Involutive_distributions). This example shows that the OP's hypotheses are not enough to guarantee that it is.

Comment: Hmm... Interesting. But my metric is actually of the form $\Theta(u,v,w)(dz)^2 + \hat{g}_{ab}(u,v,w)dx^adx^b$. Could I have such vectors? And if not, what condition am I missing? Maybe I need to say $Z$ is Killing and polarized?

Comment: OK I found it. Actually the condition I forgot to mention is the only one I need... Since the distribution generated by the level sets of $z$ is integrable it is involute and the Lie bracket stays in the hyperplane. Thanks for the answer and sorry for not taking that into account originally.

Comment: Involutivity of the distribution orthogonal to $Z$ is the only issue.

Comment: I will accept this answer, could you please edit with a short comment about that? (just in case a future reader arrives here so she does not have to go through the comments)

Comment: @Duronman: Sure, done.